# AJAX get cross-domain with WCF leads to parseerror

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, wcf

I am trying to consume a WCF Rest Service from javascript using $.ajax, I am aware that there are issues with cross-domain calls. After googling it for more than a day, I have come quite far but the last mile is missing.

First off, here is my client-code:

```js
$.ajax({
  url: "https://myurl-here/api/test?param1=x&param2=y&callback=?",
  type: 'GET',
  dataType: 'json',
  headers: {
    "Authorization": "Basic xxxxxxxxx"
  },
  success: function(data) {
    alert(data);
  },
  error: function(data, errorThrown) {
    alert(errorThrown);
  }
});
```

Note that I added the `callback=?` parameter and set the `dataType='json'`. I am debugging this using Chrome, which has some powerful tools. The response from the server is `200 OK`. However, I get an error saying:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

After googling some more, I think this error might be because the server respose is set to content-type "application/json" and the client expects "application/javascript". Here is what the debugging tool returns:

[image: 200 OK]

If I click on this and go to the response tab, I even see the plain json string from the response, which is correct and just what I want.

Now my question is: What can I do? Is there a way to tell ajax that I dont expect a script but it should just take the content and parse it as plain json? Or is there a way of ignoring the parse error and get hold of the content afterwards? The chrome debugger tool seems to somehow get hold of the content.

Or is there a way to completely get rid of this callback=? which I suspect makes the contentType to jsonp (I'm not entirely sure how this all works).

I can also change code on the server side, however there are some constraints: the server side code cannot be hosted in IIS, it is a self-hosted WCF service.

Comment: Are you sure that the endpoint you're calling is returning JSONP formatted data?

Comment: it is not returning jsonp formatted data, it is returning a pure json string

Comment: Where do you get Unexpected token? If you get your JSON and HTTP 200 it's probably some error handeling the JSON. Be sure to convert it to JSON with JSON.parse().

Comment: The code snippet above goes into the "error" method. So I suppose the JSON.parse happens under the hood of ajax. And I suppose it does not do a plain JSON.parse but rather an eval(result), because of this callback=? which I suspect to change the dataType to jsonp.

Comment: did you take a look at the data that the error function returns? Try: error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert(thrownError);
            alert(xhr.responseText);
        }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try to use:

```
dataType: 'jsonp'
```

and remove

```
&callback=?
```

from the URL.

Update:

**Update**

After receiving the response Jquery tries to validate that the response contains valid JSON. if the response is not valid JSON you will get the parse error.

- If you use dataType : 'json' and the response contains a callback like callback({ /* ... */ }) it will fail because the callback is not considered valid JSON.
- If you use dataType : 'jsonp' jquery will invoke the callback first and then validate the JSON.

You can try to use a validation tool like jsonlint.com to ensure that the returned JSON is valid. If you want to stop Jquery from validating the response, you can set the response content type as text in the server-side. In the clinet-side, and use `contentType : 'text'` in the jquery AJAX call. In the `success` callback use the JavaScript `function JSON.parse(text)` to transform the response text into JSON.

If you want your WCF service to support CORS you will need to add JSONP support or [enable CORS](http://enable-cors.org/server_wcf.html). If you decide to enable CORS you will need the Jquery ajax setting crossDomain.

Hope it helps!

Comment: I tried that, it leads to exactly the same behavior. I presume dataType: 'jsonp' and &callback=? is the same thing somehow - this is something I read during my research

Comment: The parse error is because after receiving the response Jquery tries to validate that the response contains valid JSON. If you use ``dataType : 'json'`` and the response contains a callback like ``callback({ /* ... */ })`` it will fail because the callback is not considered valid JSON. If you use ``dataType : 'jsonp'`` jquery will invoke the callback first and then and validate the JSON. Try to use a validation tool like http://jsonlint.com/ to ensure that the returned JSON is valid.

Comment: The returned json string is valid (validated it with jsonlint.com) the response does not contains this callback({...}), it contains a plain json string - is it not possible to somehow intercept the response and parse it myself?

Comment: The problem is that if you want your service to support CORS you will need to add JSONP support or enable CORS (http://enable-cors.org/server_wcf.html). Once you have enabled CORS you could return the json and set the response content type as text. Then in Jquery use ``contentType : 'text'`` and in ``success`` use the JavaScript function ``JSON.parse(text)`` to transform the response text into JSON. If you decide to enable CORS you will need the Jquery ajax setting ``crossDomain ``.

Comment: enabling CORS seems much better than returning jsonp to me. I will try the tutorial on enable-cors.org

Comment: thank you very much, enabling CORS server-side helped and solved my problem altogether. Now it is possible to make plain "json" calls to the service. Put it as an answer and I'll mark it as solved